# Native Base picker for iOS and Android with dynamically created item list

Tags: react-native, native-base, vue-native

I'm trying to write a Native Base Picker component in a Vue Native project that's compatible with both iOS and Android.  The following code works properly on both:

```
<template>
  <nb-content>
    <nb-text>Picker</nb-text>
    <nb-picker
      mode="dropdown"
      :selectedValue="selected1"
      :onValueChange="onValueChange"      
    >
      <item label="Wallet" value="key0" />
      <item label="ATM Card" value="key1" />
      <item label="Debit Card" value="key2" />
      <item label="Credit Card" value="key3" />
      <item label="Net Banking" value="key4" />

    </nb-picker>
  </nb-content>
</template>

<script>
import { Picker } from 'native-base';

export default {
  components: { Item: Picker.Item },
  data() {
    return {
      selected1: "key1"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onValueChange(value) {
      this.selected1 = value;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

That's well and good, but the next step is to make the component more reusable by having it generate the picker items from an array.  Here is my attempt at that:

```
<template>
  <nb-content>
    <nb-text>Picker</nb-text>
    <nb-picker
      mode="dropdown"
      :selectedValue="selected1"
      :onValueChange="onValueChange"      
    >
      <nb-text v-for="choice in choices" :key="choice.id">
        <item :label="choice.name" :value="choice.id" />
      </nb-text>

    </nb-picker>
  </nb-content>
</template>

<script>
import { Picker } from 'native-base';

export default {
  components: { Item: Picker.Item },
  data() {
    return {
      selected1: "key1",
      choices: [
        { id: 'key0', name: 'wallet' },
        { id: 'key1', name: 'ATM card' },
        { id: 'key2', name: 'debit card' },
        { id: 'key3', name: 'credit card' },
        { id: 'key4', name: 'net banking' }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onValueChange(value) {
      this.selected1 = value;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This fails on both iOS and Android.  On iOS no items are displayed for the picker.  On Android an error is thrown which says "Error while updating property 'items' of a view managed by: AndroidDropdownPicker"  followed by a new line that says "null" followed by another new line that says "label".  What should be changed to get it to work?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this man, same situation.

Comment: @ehijon - I just saw your comment today.  Not finding a solution for this in Native Base, I resorted to writing a React Native component instead.  See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60472136/pass-value-from-react-native-picker-component-back-to-vuejs-caller